# Why C program gives different result?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

There was a question in an exam I took. The question was:

What will be the output of the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
 int a=5, b=6, c=7;
 printf("%d%d%d");
}
```

My answer : It will give a warning as printf has not been provided with the required arguments.
And if you will run it, you will get garbage values.

The teacher gave me zero. According to him, the answer is that the values will be printed in reverse order i.e the output will be "765".

The catch is he is using the Turbo C++ compiler and I generally use GCC. Can I have some comments and explanation to get my marks back? Or is my answer really wrong?

Comment: Your teacher is relying on the function using the last three values on the stack and those last three being the three variables you declared. It's undefined behaviour all around (including the `void main` part), so it could do anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672445/c-programming-printf/12672573#12672573

Comment: You're perfectly right and your teacher is a prick.

Comment: I wouldn't see this as such a bad exam question if it said to explain one way in which it would print the 3 numbers and explain whether and why this is always the case. Of course any question involving explanation of undefined behaviour beyond "It's undefined behaviour." is a bit iffy.

Comment: Also, tell your teacher that I just tried it on my iPad, and it **did not** print `765`.

Comment: Having to fix the `void main` and `<conio.h>`, *Execution output:
-1218809868134514144-1079942696* - http://liveworkspace.org/code/aee5d93e881f1bb6ef0b49985ac0a069, not to mention a whole whack of warnings.

Comment: You could even tell him that if he compiles with optimizations on, the variables will simply vanish as the compiler will probably realize they are unused.

Comment: Your teacher is not qualified for teaching C programming. Nobody who is qualified would teach to use `void main()` since it is not valid C (on a hosted system), nobody qualified would use Turbo C since it doesn't follow the C standard, nobody qualified would compile C code on a C++ compiler, and in particular, nobody qualified would teach people to study the outcome undefined behavior. Is a pointless knowledge and a huge waste of everyone's time. It is enough to know that something _is_ undefined behavior and leave it at that.

Comment: if we compile it on some Turbo/Borland TC,TC++ software. It will print 7 6 5. But with the help GCC , garbage values for sure.

Comment: Exam questions are supposed to fool the students. As long as you learn something it is fine. I have worked on a lot of compiler and libraries from arm, gcc, vxworks and others and each have their own way of implementing things. A major part of my job is to run code on many different platforms. In a huge codebase such code would be present from time to time and would be the cause for many bugs after porting to a new platform.

Comment: Also, note that only a broken compiler would generate code to write the values 5, 6, and 7 anywhere in memory. Since they are unused, they should not even exist.

Comment: By the way, I think you should show this question to the head of your department. Your instructor is not qualified to be teaching, and they should be informed of this.

Comment: @Lundin Indian universities are sadly still in 1993... :(

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer This question was however just as much nonsense in 1993 as it is today. The problem here isn't outdated knowledge, but lack of knowledge entirely.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is an undefined behavior, so absolutely anything can happen.

The local variables *might* be actually printed, because on some systems `Xprintf` functions family might pop their arguments off the stack (stdarg.h facilities could be used for implementation of such functions). Your variables `a,b,c` might happen to be at the memory location from which `va_arg` macro will take extract the arguments. These are the details of library implementation / execution environment and are not part of the standard, so they can vary across different target platforms.

Here is a quote from c99 standard describing `fprintf` function:

> **7.19.6.1 The fprintf function**
>
> 2/ The fprintf function writes output to the stream pointed to by
>   stream, under control of the string pointed to by format that
>   specifies how subsequent arguments are converted for output. **If there
>   are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.**
>   If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess
>   arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored. The
>   fprintf function returns when the end of the format string is
>   encountered.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that `printf` pops its arguments off the stack -- or that there is such a thing as "the stack".

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Need to be careful about what I'm saying. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @MaximSkurydin and all others, now my teacher has agreed that my answer is right but now i think he is kind of pissed of from me and i will surly get a C Grade in final exams. :( But, who cares, i still love programming.

Answer (score 2):

Mismatch of arguments in `printf` and giving no arguments (as in this question )is

```
undefined behaviour
```

It may get `garbage` or may get those values `a,b,c` .
It's not defined by language standard.